# Select @var = temporal table result from function SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If I have a function that returns a temporal table, how do I set a var in SQL Server that saves it?

If the result of the function is something like:

```
temp table
    item1 item2...itemn
        1     2...    n
```

Is this valid?

```
SELECT @table = * FROM dbo.SOME_FUNCTION()
```

??

If this is possible, could you make an example, of how to use the `@table` var for knowing values?

If not possible, how can I access the temp table that the function returns??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the function is returning a table, you should be able to have:

```
INSERT INTO @table (Col1, Col2) SELECT * FROM dbo.SOME_FUNCTION()
```

You'd need to specify the columns you're going to be using for either the INSERT or SELECT portion of the statement.

UPDATE:

Here's something I've come up with so you can find out the columns. The first part is enabling your server so it can return and use stored procs as you would a normal table (check with your DBA or whoever runs the server that they're ok with these options being turned on). You select your resultset into a temp table, then run the `sp_columns` stored proc in `tempdb` and insert that into another temp table (which you then drop). That way, you at least know what columns you've got, and can possibly use that to make it easier to work with dynamic column names perhaps.

```
sp_configure 'Show Advanced Options', 1
GO

RECONFIGURE
GO

sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
GO

RECONFIGURE
GO

SELECT * INTO #ItemsTable FROM dbo.SOME_FUNCTION()

SELECT * INTO #Columns FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=(local);Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'exec tempdb..sp_columns ''#ItemsTable''')

SELECT COLUMN_NAME FROM #Columns

DROP TABLE #Columns
```

ANOTHER UPDATE:

If you want to get the list of columns for a table in the database, you could use this query:

```
SELECT [name] FROM sys.columns WHERE object_id = (SELECT object_id FROM sys.tables WHERE [name] = 'TableName')
```

However! If you're going to be running this query and creating tables of varying sizes many times a day, I would suggest that you stick with temp tables. That way you won't be writing unnecessarily to the database (except tempdb). If for some reason you NEED permanent tables created each time, then, I guess that's fine too!

Comment: how does @table look like after that instruction?

Comment: @darkcminor: It will contain the results of `SELECT * FROM dbo.SOME_FUNCTION()`, which is why you need to ensure the @table column definitions line up with the returned column definitions from your table function.

Comment: You'll need to declare the table as if it were a regular table. like: Declare @MyTable TABLE (id int, col1 varchar(255)) etc. etc.

Comment: Excuse me, one question, As im getting an unknow table from that function, (this could return a table with 5 columns, 6,7...n columns) how can I declare the fields if I do not know the table I am receiving???

Comment: @darkcminor: See my answer below if you do not know the schema of the table you are receiving from that function.  If I can ask, what are you planning on doing with the results if you do not know what columns to expect back?

Comment: @nybbler with the result Im getting from that function I need to do some calculus with some of the fields, I posted a question more less with I want to acomplish, thats why I needed A new table: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4953477/access-unkown-columns-of-a-table-and-insert-them-into-a-new-one-mssql

Comment: sorry about that, I tried to divide the problem in many questions, with the answers Im trying to tied them up, and solve the biggest problem

Comment: @darkcminor - If you don't know what columns you are getting back, how will you know if you need to do something like Item1 * Item5, or Item1 * Item10? I read your other question, and I have a possible solution for you, but I just want to see if you've already worked out how to do the calculations on the newly returned, but unknown columns.

Comment: Yeah, 
1.-suppose you get a temp table from a function.                    
2.-you get the size of that table, lets say d columns.              
3.-In a new table, you insert some calculus as described in other   question, that is, no matter how many columns, in this case d       
columns                                                             
4.-the new columns in other table will correspond as the rule I described in the other question.                                    
5.-The problem here is that all depends of the result of the function, this is, the table we get from that function.

Comment: I have tried it out, with a while loop, doing several selects, the stop criteria is the size of columns of the table result from function, but I got no luck....

Comment: @darkcminor - check my edit to the answer. That might help you out.

Comment: After executing the code you provide, I get an empty table with fileds like:
TABLE_QUALIFIER,TABLE_OWNER_TABLE_NAME...How can I make the calculus with the data, still dont get it...where are the names of table??,

Comment: If you are using temp tables rather than table variables (#TableName rather than @TableName), the temp table information is stored and can be queried using the method above. The only thing I would suggest is making sure that the table name you select into (for example #Items) is the same in the OPENROWSET(...) section. That might be why you didn't get any results.

Comment: One more, If I change the result to get a table, not a temporal, but a fix table, How do I get the results as if the table were temporal, as you described?

Comment: I've added some more code. Use the new code to replace the OPENROWSET(...) and SELECT COLUMN_NAME... lines.

Answer (score 1):

Using your example:

```
Declare @table TABLE
(
Item1 int,
Item2 int,
Item3 int
)

INSERT INTO @table (Item1, Item2, Item3) SELECT * FROM dbo.SOME_FUNCTION()
```

Answer (score 0):

With SQL Server 2008, you also have INSERT avaiable ([MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188029.aspx))

With this, you should be able to do:

```
SELECT * 
INTO new_table 
FROM dbo.SOME_FUNCTION()
```

The added benefit to this is that you won't have to declare your local table variable first.  From the MSDN Documentation reference comes this excerpt regarding *new_table*:

> Specifies the name of a new table to
>   be created, based on the columns in
>   the select list and the rows chosen
>   from the data source.