# access unkown columns of a table and insert them into a new one

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like:

```
item1 item2 item3  item4...  itemn
    1     2     3      4...      n
```

If I need to do some calculus with some variables lets say  powers and sqrt with item1,item3, and insert it in column 1 of a new table, and then the same operations but with item2 and item4 and then insert it in column 2 of new table,...  well something like:

```
new table
      column1        column2       column3      .. columnsn-1        columnsn
      item1*item3    item2*item4   item3*item5  .. itemn-1*item1  itemn *item2
```

But as the column names are variable (aka different tables) I dont know how to accomplish and get the values of specific columns, Could you please help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a way to extract the name and the order of the column:

```
select name, colorder from syscolumns where id = (select id from sysobjects where name = [tablename])
```

You can use this to manipulate with the data refering to its order in table instead of name

Comment: If my table has a single row,  How Do I get the column value too?, 
you put name, colorder, AND THE VALUE?...

Comment: @darkcminor: If your table has a single row, you can create a temporary table #tmp(id, value), where id is the colorder and for value insert the values for every column, and then you can easily manipulate the data.